# How do I paste the audioinfo of a music file?

Tags: matlab

I want to be able to update a text box with the audioinfo of a sound file.

The current solution I have gives me an error

```
info = audioinfo('music1.mp3');
set(handles.edit1,'String',info);
```

Running `info` in the console gives me all the information about the sound file and stores it in the workspace to the right of MATLAB. I want all that information to update a textbox (`edit1`).

Error:

```
While setting the 'String' property of 'UIControl':
String should be char, numeric or cell array datatype.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you [read the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioinfo.html#outputarg_info) you would see that `audioinfo` returns a structure, not a string.

Comment: @excaza do you know how I would go about listing this structure on a textbox?

Comment: All the information? What if the field is empty?

Comment: @excaza yes all the information. If the field is empty I can just list it as `empty`, doesn't really matter, I just want to concentrate on getting the information there as I have no clue how I would do it other than the provided solution.

Comment: Does it have to be a text box?

Comment: @excaza Not really. As long as I can see the text and it can get updated within the application then it's all good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a [`uitable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) rather than an `'edit'` [`uicontrol` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html). `'edit' uicontrol` objects can only be one line so they can't be used anyway, and the alternative, `'listbox'` can only be one column so you would need to `sprintf`/`fprintf` the data to get it to fit.

For example:

```
% Generate audio file
load handel.mat
filename = 'handel.wav';
audiowrite(filename,y,Fs);
clear y Fs

% Build dummy GUI
f = figure('ToolBar', 'none');
T = uitable('Parent', f, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);

% Read data and add to table
info = audioinfo(filename);
T.RowName = fieldnames(info);
T.Data = struct2cell(info);
```

Results in the following UI:

[image: yay]

Which also allows you to easily manipulate the data (e.g. copy, edit, etc.)

Answer (score -4):

You will need to download mp3read and write functionality from matLab

[mp3read](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6152-mp3write-and-mp3read)

Now use `info = mp3read('music.mp3')` which returns an array containing the raw audio.

Then, you can turn that array into a string using `result = mat2string(info)`

Then you can set the result in your UI...

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: i was under the impression that he wanted the raw audio data displayed.

Comment: How is an edit box filled with doubles a useful display of a sound?